# How to customize SharePoint Designer Workflow Task form in SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I'm trying to customize layout, add javascript and change some other visuals in SharePoint Designer workflow task form. I'm using SP Online and this is related to SharePoint 2013 Workflow (not SharePoint 2010). 
Previous versions generate InfoPath or ASPX forms for each task. 2013 does not. Instead it uses content types for tasks but tasks always open in edit mode using a common EditForm.aspx located in ../WorkflowTasks/EditForm.aspx
I suppose changing this form will affect all workflows on that site, which is not the goal.

Is there a way to force SPD to create a dedicated edit form for each individual workflow task? I tried to change the Edit Form attribute on a content type used with my existing tasks but it has no effect. 
I can browse WorkflowTasks folder contents in SPD and each associated content type gets a respective folder. I thought SPD would put task forms in there but that's not the case.

Anyone has an idea?

How do I go about creating SPD workflow and edit the ASPX task forms?

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom content type based on Workflow Task (SharePoint 2013) content type.

You can then select a custom content type in your task.
[image]

See https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/171646/custom-task-forms-edit-display-new-in-sharepoint-2013-online-office-365 for additional info.